# Finding a lock combination

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

Here is a puzzle that I recently encountered:

You have a four digit lock with the following clues.

- When you enter 1378, one digit is correct and well-placed.
- When you enter 2834, nothing is correct.
- When you enter 7512, two numbers are correct. Both are wrongly placed.
- When you enter 1693, one number is correct but wrongly placed
- When you enter 2350, one digit is correcr but in the wrong place. One number is correct and well placed.

Find any four digit number that may be the lock code.

Comment: "When you enter 2350, one digit is correct but in the wrong place. One number is correct and well placed." - What exactly do you mean? Is the number in the right place or the wrong place?

Comment: There are two correct numbers. One is well placed but the other isn't

Comment: [Bulls and Cows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulls_and_Cows) have many automatic solvers (e.g. [this one](https://frank-deng.github.io/bulls-cows-solver/)). BTW I'm a bit surprised that `bulls-and-cows` is not an existing tag on this site.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand this correctly,

> From the first two codes, we can say that 2,8,3,4 are not correct. Hence, either 1 or 7 is in the actual code.
>  From the third code, we can say that **5 is definitely part of the actual code**. It's just not in the 2nd position.
>  From the 5th code(if I understand correctly), **5 and 0 are part of the actual code**. One of them is in the correct position and one of them isn't.
>  From the 4th code, we can confirm that "1" is indeed not part of the code as the digit is supposed to be wrongly placed and it would contradict the message of the first code. Hence, **it's either 6 or 9 in the actual code.**

So far, we can say,

> ??7? is the code that we have.
>  We can also confirm that "5" in the last code is the wrongly placed digit and "0" is the correctly placed digit. So, 5 is in either the first or second position. From the third code, we can say 5 can't be in the second spot. So, 5 has to be in the first spot.
>  Hence, our code so far is, 5?70.

Finally

> From the 4th code, we know "9" has to be either in the first or the second position and "6" can only be in the first position.

So the combination of codes:

> 5970

Comment: Guess I can delete my draft now